# 7 Wonders Resource Clarification

Tags: 7-wonders

I am trying to learn how to play the Game 7 Wonders. How many of what resources do each of the wonders start the game with?

The instruction manual never actually tells you how to know what resources each wonder starts out the game with.

Comment: Bear in mind that nobody really "starts out" with resources in 7 Wonders - you just start out with the power to get N amount of resources each turn, if you need it to pay costs on cards.  You probably knew that already, but I thought it might be worth pointing out - 7 Wonders works quite differently in this respect from other popular resource-involving games like, e.g., Settlers of Catan...

Answer (score 13):

This question indicates a common misunderstanding of the way resources work in 7 Wonders. **Resources are not collected and spent**; you can build any card (building or Wonder stage) that requires resources as long as you have your own access to those resources, or pay a neighbor for the temporary use of theirs. If you do not have the required resources, and cannot acquire them from your neighbors, you can't build the card or Wonder stage.

Coins work differently as a building cost; when they are required, such as for the brown split-resource cards, they are paid to the bank.

Answer (score 9):

The resource is pictured in the upper left. You can see it in the [rules on page 8 or 9](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_COLOR.pdf)

- The Colossus of Rhodes: Ore
- The Hanging Gardens of Babylon: Clay
- The Pyramids of Giza: Stone
- The Lighthouse of Alexandria: Glass
- The Mausoleum of Halicarnassus: Textile
- The Temple of Artemis in Ephesus: Papyrus
- The Statue of Zeus in Olympia: Timber